# Error "shockwave flash has crashed " google chrome ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, flash, crash

I can not watch videos on twitch because **shockwave flash** crashes. 
I tried to disable the flash in the plugins but I only seen one **Flash** plugin.

Before when I used 12.10, I saw 3 plugins for **Flash**, and I could disable one to allow me to watch Twitch. Not anymore. Does anyone have any idea what my issue is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shockwave Flash crashes with Chromium and Firefox](http://askubuntu.com/questions/369405/shockwave-flash-crashes-with-chromium-and-firefox)

Comment: What language do you speak? Ubuntu Support is offered in all languages.

Comment: why don't you try wine,torch then adobe...

Answer (score -1):

Your answer indicates that you may have upgraded from 12.10 to 14.04. If this is the case, upgrading from 12.10 to 14.04 is not supported, because 12.10 was a short term release.

I have 14.04, I am running google chrome, and I can watch youtube and twitchTV without a problem. What you should do is this:

1. Backup the files on your computer to an external harddrive, or to a cloud provider such as **Dropbox** or **Google Drive**.
2. Download the latest Ubuntu Version
3. Place the latest version on an installation medium such as a DVD or USB thumb drive.
4. Restart computer, and boot up the DVD/USB installation image of ubuntu.
5. Assuming this is **not** a dual boot setup; do a clean install of Ubuntu, wiping the entire harddrive.

After this is done; you should have a clean and fresh setup where you should not have any issues watching twitch or youtube. You should be able to do this in both Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Thanks but no install ubuntu 14.04 from 0, it is a clean install, this is my flash: 
Adobe Flash Player - Version: 14.0.0.145 
Shockwave Flash 14.0 r0

Answer (score -1):

Open Terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), then type this command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Afterwards, restart your PC and it should work.

Comment: -1 Upgrading packages is a very generic solution approach, if done without further knowledge of the issue. If it works, it's sheer luck.