# Ubuntu 15.10 - Shockwave crash

Tags: google-chrome, 15.10, browser

I'm on ubuntu 15.10 and shockwave crashes for some videos. It seems to be mostly on ad based content, I can run pandora all day without an issue. Installing an ad blocker helped a little but I'd rather fix the issue. Any ideas? I was trying to find if I can just update flash alone.

Answer (score 0):

After 11.02 version, Shockwave has stopped support for Linux.

For detailed information refer to answer: [Shockwave Flash crashes with Chromium and Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369405/shockwave-flash-crashes-with-chromium-and-firefox)

A possible work around is that you can install the Windows version of Shockwave using wine, as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Shockwave).

Other possible reason for your problem may be is that you are using Ubuntu 15.10 which is quite not as stable as Ubuntu LTS versions like **14.04(Trusty Tahr)** and the upcoming **16.04(Xenial Xerus)**.

Comment: It was actually me using a quadro nvidia card. I picked up a $40 geforce gt 610 and all issues are resolved.